# What is the difference between "ecological succession" and the term "stage of regeneration", is there a difference between them?

Tags: ecology, terminology

In ecology what is the meaning of the term "ecological succession" and the term "stage of regeneration", is there a difference between them?

Edit 1: Perhaps the term "Stage of ecological succession" is in English "ecological succession".

Comment: Where do you find the terms used? It's best to provide some context around questions asked here.

Comment: This term exists in Portuguese, I don't know if there is another term in English

Comment: Though this site is English-only, if you're taking something from Portuguese and taking a literal translation I think it's important to mention that in the question body. You're probably best off following citations in the Portuguese text to others in English, though.

Comment: Second other comments. It would be nice to know if you are talking about restoration ecology, forestry, disturbance ecology, or something else. "stage of regeneration" implies some of the above. There may be terminology that's specific to the field or the type of ecosystem.